# Venmo API call from client side. Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: ajax, ember.js, firebase, venmo

I'm building a small web app with Ember.js and Firebase so as of now I don't have a framework.  I'm trying to use Venmo's OAuth and API to get usernames, emails, and friends.  I got OAuth to work and I get a client-side access token to use in an API call, but whenever I try and send a GET to `https://api.venmo.com/v1/me?access_token=<access_token>` using AJAX or CORS I get an error saying `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.venmo.com/v1/me?access_token=<access_token>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.  Is there a way to do this with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm an API engineer over @ Venmo, and we're looking to open up CORS support very soon, in the next couple months hopefully. Feel free to email developer@venmo.com and bug us if you need to :P

Comment: Thanks Matthew!  I appreciate the info and the Venmo team in general.  You guys are great.

Comment: Have you guys opened it up yet? I can't seem to access CORS at the /me endpoint.